# How / Why is SyncRoot hidden on Queue<T>?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, interface

Confused and might be missing something simple..

I've got

```
var q = new Queue<object>();
lock (q.SyncRoot)
{
    ...
}
```

I get

```
Queue<T> does not provide a defintion for SyncRoot blah blah...
```

but, `Queue<T>` implements `ICollection` which defines `SyncRoot` as a public property.

So, first of all, why is this hidden. Second, how can you hide a property of an interface you're implementing?

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to do? I assume since your trying to use `SyncRoot` you are trying to avoid concurrent writing to your queue - I would recommend using [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx)

Comment: @James I like to explicitly lock it. It makes it more obvious to me what's happening when reading the code.

Comment: I fail to see where you lose readability here, but fair enough. Some people enjoy the challenge of trying to re-invent the wheel :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hide the property by [implementing it explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
    object MyQueue.SyncRoot { get; set; }
```

It is hidden [because it's deprecated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/09/28/50391.aspx):

> We found the SyncRoot-based synchronization APIs to be insufficiently flexible for most scenarios. The APIs allow for thread safe access to a single member of a collection. The problem is that there are numerous scenarios where you need to lock on multiple operations (for example remove one item and add another). In other words, it’s usually the code that uses a collection that wants to choose (and can actually implement) the right synchronization policy, not the collection itself. We found that SyncRoot is actually used very rarely and in cases where it is used, it actually does not add much value. In cases where it’s not used, it is just an annoyance to implementers of ICollection.

Comment: This seems really hacky. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 3):

It is an example of "[explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx)."

When you implement an interface explicitly, you can *only* access that method via a reference of that type of that instance. In other words, if you cast that `Queue` to an `ICollection`, you will see the sync root member.

Comment: +1 for dedication to answering from a phone. I'm commenting from my phone right now as well.